# Ruby On Rails: Get md5 hash of paperclip image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, paperclip, md5

I am uploading an image to a ruby on rails server using a gem called paperclip. The image is uploaded correctly and is working. I am working on using md5 hashes so that a single request to the rails server can be made, returning to my script exactly what images need to be uploaded (I do not want duplicates).

In the script I am calculating the md5 successfully with

`require 'digest/md5'` and `md5 = Digest::MD5.file(filename).hexdigest`

On the server in order to check if the md5s are the same (image to be uploaded vs image on the server) I need to calculate the md5 of each paperclip image on the server.

Images are called TestImages and the model looks like this

```
class TestImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {thumbnail: '100x100', small: '350x350'}
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: {content_type: ["application/octet-stream", "multipart/form-data", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]}
  belongs_to :build
  belongs_to :test
end
```

People have said that paperclip has added the functionality of a fingerprint (md5 representation) but I am unsure as to how to set that up. It seems it is done automatically but needs to be stored as a column in the database? Here is one other post I was looking at [Rails: How does MD5 checksum work in paperclip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282130/rails-how-does-md5-checksum-work-in-paperclip)

If it doesn't work with using paperclip (paperclip fingerprint) I could do the same digest/md5 method as in the script but I can't seem to find the full image path of the paperclip image.

Using this did not work
`image.md5 = Digest::MD5.file(test_image.image.path).hexdigest`

This gave the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/scott.bishop/Code/visual-automation/public/system/test_images/images//original/testBasic_2x.png):
  app/controllers/test_images_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

I'm not sure what path it wants. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the paperclip image path works.

```
require 'digest/md5'
image.md5 = Digest::MD5.file(PAPER_CLIP_IMAGE.path).hexdigest
```